# If a category has a set of objects then any of its coequalizers has a set of objects

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove the following statement:

If $A$ has a set of objects, so does the coequalizer of any parallel pair with codomain $A$.

Here a set of objects is defined as a mono $s:S\to A$ such that $S$ is a discrete category and every map to $A$ from a discrete category factors through $s$.

This is a theorem in McLarty's paper "Axiomatizing a Category of Categories", Theorem 22. The original proof there says:

Use the fact that any coequalizer is the coequalizer of its kernel pair, and the fact that if a category $A$ is discrete, then for every parallel pair $t_1,t_2:T\to A$, the coequalizer of $t_1$ and $t_2$ is discrete.

Here is a link to the paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275472?casa_token=hi4gsrP5DHMAAAAA:l5929tBx2JWhyJS9B1aoR8iB3AaD1o8NByGOmoj2MHTMoI-LrnB4EzfRSa-si01RyxIz4dHbuldXesD-x9LvW-TmmojxoTMS7XbUrNWEsykCsx0p

I do not get it. Could someone please give an expanded explanation? A proof is ideal, but more hints are appraciated as well.

My guess is that given arrows $f_1,f_2:X\to A$ and their coequalizer $q:A\to Q$, the set of objects of $Q$ is the image of $S$ in the coequalizer. That is, if mono-epi factorization exists, the set of objects of $Q$ will be the mono to $Q$ which is the factorised mono part of $q\circ s$, but it does not seem such factorisation exists in such a workspace. Therefore I am confused. Is there any way to construct such a factorization by hand?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I think I get it. Given $f_1,f_2:B\to A$ and their coequalizer $q:A\to Q$, take the kernel pair $s_1,s_2:K\to S$ of the composition $q\circ s:S\to E$. Then take the coequalizer $q_0:S\to Qs$ of $s_1$ and $s_2$, then $Qs$ is the set of objects of $Q$, it is discrete as a coequalizer of maps to a discrete category. We want a map $qs:Qs\to Q$ which is a mono. This mono is obtained by factor the composition $q\circ s$ through $q_0$, since it agrees on $s_1$ and $s_2$. This is a mono since to check maps from or to a discrete category equal, it is sufficient to check on objects.

Comment: You still need to check that any $S'\to Q$ factors through $Qs\to Q$ for any discrete $S'$. It may be enough to use the fact that $Qs\to Q$ is onto on objects, but I haven't read the paper carefully enough to be sure.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I have checked. This is true. To check the factorization we need the fact that both of the equalizers here are onto for objects, which is Theorem 15 in the paper.

Comment: Sorry, for checking the factorization, we only use $q$ is surjective on objects. Given $d:1\to Q$, we have $q\circ d_0:1\to A = d$, for some $d_0$, such a $d_0$ is a map from a discrete category since $1$ is discrete, then we have $d_0 = s\circ d_{00}$ for some $d_{00}:1\to S$, sending $d_{00}$ to $Q_0$ by applying $q_0$ gives us the factorization.